# Can I take back a promise made to kali?

Tags: vedas, sin, kali

I(29M) made a promise to goddess kali that I will stop watching porn/masturbation. But I could not keep up this how hard I try. I have been stuck in this for 8 years and in one way or the other I always tend to break this. Everytime I slip, It feels like something bad happens to my life and this is terribly affecting my personal and professional life.

I wanted to be a better person by giving up porn/masturbation. I thought fear of this promise would help me get to that state. But this has been highly counter productive, I have been feeling terrible mentally everytime I slip.

This is affecting my health to some extent as well. Can someone please help me find a way where I can take back my promise? I just want to live like others as a normal person.